# XMLHttpRequest and save file?

Tags: javascript, xml, http, ubuntu, download

I am looking at creating an application in QT Creator for the Ubuntu touch environment for managing EVE online information. Much like the eve neocom app for Iphone. I need a starting point and since this is going to be a read only app I need info.

So I need a way to download and save a file via javascript.

download an xml file from the specified site

https://api.eveonline.com/account/characters.xml.aspx?keyID=xxxxxx&vCode=xxxxxxxxx

and save it in a folder (same number as keyID) as characters.xml, so I can later read it offline.

the xml file on the server has this info

```
<eveapi version="2">
<currentTime>2013-06-29 05:37:02</currentTime>
<result>
<rowset name="characters" key="characterID" columns="name,characterID,corporationName,corporationID">
<row name="nawm oloektan" characterID="xxxxxxxx" corporationName="Str8ngeBrew" corporationID="xxxxxxxx"/>
</rowset>
</result>
<cachedUntil>2013-06-29 06:34:02</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

this is the function I have so far for loading/reloading the xml file from server

```
function RefreshChar(keyID, vCode) {
    var baseurl = "https://api.eveonline.com"
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    var code = "?keyID=" + keyID + "&vCode=" + vCode

    request.open("GET", baseurl + "/account/characters.xml.aspx?keyID=" + code)

}
```

I need to save the xml file and be able to read it later on using qml (QT creator)

Comment: you probably won't be able to straight-up download the xml, unless eve sends cors headers or offers a jsonp API. you might be able to fetch the API data using YQL or Yahoo Pipes, but it depends on how they configure the eve server. lastly, you actually wouldn't want to save it in a folder to use later, as JS can't get to any folders; use localStorage instead.

Comment: I should not need JS to pull from folder later on I will end up using QML import to bring in the  /folder/file.xml to read